# Trying to store user values into an array

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create an array of a user set length that users can add values to that will be saved and output on multiple sheets. I am very new to VBA so I do not know if what I am trying to do is possible but I have tried a few methods unsuccessfully.

This is the code I have so far

```
Sub addCost()
    Dim costArray() As Variant
    ReDim Preserve costArray(1 To Range("b2").Value)

    For i = 1 To Range("b2").Value
        costArray(i) = 0
    Next i

    Dim newCost As Variant
    Dim costYear As Variant

    newCost = InputBox("New cost amount:")
    costYear = InputBox("Year new cost is active:")

    costArray(costYear) = newCost
End Sub
```

[Here is what the input tab looks like in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okV46.png)

With the length of the array being the project lifespan and the add new cost activating the code, clear costs are still in progress. Is there a way for the array to store after multiple executions of the addCost sub?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/miscellaneous/storing-values-when-a-macro-ends) Microsoft shows some methods of store values after the macro ending (in your case, sub addCost)

I think the first solution will be good for you.

Other solutions is use Access to store data (specially if you need these data over time) or a new and clean worksheet where you can store array entries in a cell (This is a very practical solution if the number of entries does not get too big)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).